# Use swagger in angular and typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have this autogenerated api to call a service:

```
namespace API.Client {
'use strict';

   export class MyApi {
   ...
```

I try to use it in my controller.ts by doing:

```
import TDRService = API.Client.MyApi;

export class MyController {
private tdrservice: TDRService;

/* @ngInject */
constructor(tdrservice: TDRService) {
    this.tdrservice = tdrservice;
}
```

And in my module.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./components/API/Client/api.d.ts" />
import TDRService = API.Client.MyApi;

 angular.module('myApp', [...])
.service('TDRService', TDRService)
```

But I receive the angular error: "ReferenceError: API is not defined".
How can I import correctly the class in the namespace??

Comment: I think the proper syntax is `declare namespace API.Client` (see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c2c22c3b953fe9730d4802022d5e0d18d083909e/react/react-addons-create-fragment.d.ts#L8)

Comment: If I do it I receive a lot of 'Statements are not allowed in ambient context' and 'Initializers are not allowed in ambient context'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an angular service with a typescript rest Client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831325/create-an-angular-service-with-a-typescript-rest-client)