# Create an angular service with a typescript rest Client

Tags: angularjs, typescript, swagger

I am using Angular 1.4.7 with typescript
I have an autogenerated Client with Swagger in typescript to call a rest service like this:

```
module API.Client {
'use strict';

export class DefaultApi {
    ...
```

I am trying to use it by doing:

```
import TDRService = API.Client.DefaultApi;

export class ListaTrtController {
    private tdrservice: TDRService;

/* @ngInject */
constructor(service: TDRService) {
     this.tdrservice = service;
}
```

But I receive the error "Unknown provider: serviceProvider <- service <- ListaTrtController".
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is your API registered as part of your angular.module() definition? Angular has to somehow know where to get the things you inject.

Comment: Oh, actually looks like it is the controller you might forgot to register. angular.module(..).controller('ListaTrtController', ListaTrtController)

Comment: yeah I have     .service('DefaultApi', DefaultApi)

Comment: I registered the controller, it doesn't find the service

Comment: The parameter for your constructor function is named `service` ... that means Angular is expecting you to declare a service with that name. But it looks like you're using 'DefaultApi' as the name. Change the parameter in the constructor so that it has the same name as the service ('DefaultApi').

Answer (score 3):

Register your service in angular with the name that you will use in the injections.

```
module API.Client {
'use strict';

export class DefaultApi {
    ...

angular.module('yourmodule').service('TDRService', DefaultApi);
```

Angular will use the variable name (Not the type), so it has to be the same name as it was registered in angular. And, you can use `private` in the constructor instead of doing the assignment like you did.

```
import TDRService = API.Client.TDRService;

export class ListaTrtController {

/* @ngInject */
constructor(private TDRService: TDRService) {
}
```